# Is there a way to get Stack Overflow "Recent inbox messages" via Telegram Messenger?

Tags: discussion, notifications, global-inbox

The question is really simple, is there a possibility?

Through the RSS Feed Bot or some other form that is already used by members here in the Community and can share how it can be used.

For example:

[image]

I have three communities linked to Stack Overflow that I get the new questions via RSS Feed for this bot.

If there was a main Stack bot in Telegram Messenger, to be able to receive our notifications of new messages, new alerts and everything else possible, everyone who works and uses Telegram would have notifications quite easily.

Just need a click on the link to access and already go to the question or answer and help more quickly.

*I am trying to create one for myself that will list notifications in Google Sheets and then I will use another script to send to Telegram. Only this way there is no way to create one that everyone can use.
I'll share it when it's done, but this form is very poorly made, would not be something standardized and not an easy way for everyone to use.*

**Adding something they taught me that can help anyone who sees this question (regarding how to send Stack Overflow notifications to Google Sheets):**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58827585/11462274

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time, money and donuts.

Comment: Use the RSS feed plus IFTTT?

Comment: @DanBron I did not understand very well. I use @ rss2tg_bot for the RSS feed. I searched for StackOverflow on IFTTT but it has nothing related, no device that joins the two services.

Comment: What in the world is Telegram, and why would we want to integrate it with Stack Overflow?

Comment: @CodyGray Telegram is one of today's greatest messengers, where many companies and programmers have accounts, discussion groups, and idea-sharing channels.

Whatsapp has no bot functionality, Telegram has, in addition to e-mail, it would be a nice way for people to be able to receive notifications and to know more about their notifications.

Comment: One of the greatest messengers that people have not heard of? Sounds no different than what a bot could do in Discord, Slack or any other chat program that supports bots.

Comment: One of today’s greatest messengers, eh? They should perhaps be paying you commission to market their service. I still don’t understand, though. If it’s a discussion channel, why would you want to route offsite notifications into it?

Comment: Sorry, I really see him as one of the greatest messengers today, here in Brazil the dispute is totally between Whatsapp and Telegram, so I said he is one of the biggest. Maybe out of here this is not reality. I'm a layman on the subject. I only use it because it meets my needs. About the notifications, I thought that if you received there, it would be a way for the person to know that there are news in questions that she participated, besides the email that is already possible today.

Comment: What is Telegram? [Telegram Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_(software))?

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't like the way you handled it, saying I'm getting paid to advertise. Strange to be treated that way just because I thought I had a cool tip to make my life easier and maybe it would help other people too.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Exactly mate.

Comment: @JoeW Sorry for my bad english, I'm brazilian ... But you said people never heard of Telegram? Are you sure about that? Alright that outside of Brazil may not be so well known, but i think is a bit of exaggeration. 4,164,480 times have already downloaded it from Google Play, it's a little hard to say that it's an unknown messenger.

Comment: My comment was in regards to the responses you had in your question about what it was. And while you may think it is a great messaging service having bots to help with it isn't exactly uncommon these days especially with messaging services that have desktop clients.

Comment: I understood @JoeW, thanks for explanation... In fact, it would be cool if all bot-messengers had the same service for people to get Stack notifications when they are not online at the site. The idea went to Telegram because that's where I use it, but if everyone else had it, it would be even better.

Comment: Sorry, that part of my comment was meant as a joke. I was not accusing you of actually being a marketing shill, just amusing myself at your phrasing.

Comment: @Frederico Mattos: I may have seen Telegram in passing, but I had to look it up to understand what it was. And [I have seen a lot](http://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_2019-11-01.html)... Telegram Messenger has [now been added](https://github.com/PeterMortensen/Edit_Overflow/commit/093505eeff33555b0d5ddbda3801bae321e4263d) and will be [public](http://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow1.html) soon (probably tomorrow).

Answer (score 6):

I guess you could write a Telegram bot that uses this API call: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox

You'd need to authenticate in order to grant the bot permission to make that API call on your behalf.

To my knowledge this hasn't been done yet.